¿Cómo puede calcular diferencia de horas entre dos zonas horarias en javascript?
Necesito un algoritmo para obtener la diferencia en horas entre dos zonas horarias, ejemplo:
// Zona horaria del usuario 
const fecha1 = new Date();

// Zona horaria a obtener diferencia, por ejemplo zona horaria de Sidney en Australia
const fecha2 = new Date().toLocaleString("es-ES",{timeZone: "Australia/Sidney"})


Como lo harías tu? Se trata de conseguir la diferencia de horas entre la fecha actual y la hora actual de otro país, por ejemplo la zona horaria de Sidney en Australia donde ya son las 01:18, se trata de conseguir la diferencia exacta de horas entre ellos

Lo que indicas en la pregunta y el comentario anterior a este son 2 cosas diferentes,  si estás buscando ya con zonas horarias, eso ya es un tema de discusión amplio. Define bien tu problema en la pregunta.

Si fallo mío voy a editar la pregunta

Para calcular la diferencia de horas entre dos zonas horarias en JavaScript, puedes utilizar el objeto Date y la biblioteca Intl.DateTimeFormat para obtener la información de la zona horaria. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:


function getTimeZoneOffsetInHours(timeZone) {
    const now = new Date();
    const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
        timeZone,
        hour12: false,
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric',
    });

    const formattedDate = formatter.formatToParts(now).reduce((acc, part) => {
        acc[part.type] = part.value;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    const utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(
        formattedDate.year,
        formattedDate.month - 1,
        formattedDate.day,
        formattedDate.hour,
        formattedDate.minute,
        formattedDate.second
    ));

    return (now - utcDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60); // Convert milliseconds to hours
}

function getTimeZoneDifference(timeZone1, timeZone2) {
    const offset1 = getTimeZoneOffsetInHours(timeZone1);
    const offset2 = getTimeZoneOffsetInHours(timeZone2);

    return offset2 - offset1;
}

// Ejemplo de uso:
const timeZone1 = 'America/New_York';
const timeZone2 = 'Europe/London';

const differenceInHours = getTimeZoneDifference(timeZone1, timeZone2);
console.log(`Diferencia de horas entre ${timeZone1} y ${timeZone2}: ${differenceInHours} horas`);





Muchas gracias, ya lo probé y me funcionó bien.

Gracias boss, era justo lo que buscaba!

@Fragoso, edité tu respuesta para poner tu código en un snippet, que sirve para ejecutar HTML/CSS/Javascript directamente aquí en el navegador, en la respuesta. Se hace con el botón <>. Un saludo.
